# Distributed postgresql ID collision handling

Tags: sql, postgresql, merge, distributed, eventual-consistency

Let's imagine we have a distributed table with an ID, CONTENT and TIMESTAMP. The ID is hash(CONTENT) and the CONTENT is deterministic enough to be entered in multiple places in the system, shortly after each other.

Let's say a certain real life event happened. Like someone won the Olympics. Then that goes into this database in a record that always looks the same, except for the timestamp. As each machine observes the event at slightly different delays.

So. As the machines sync this distributed table they will wonder "We have this exact ID already! It's also not an identical row! What should we do!?". I want to give them the answer in the form of:`bool compare(row a, row b)` or, preferably, `row merge(row a, row b)`.

Does anyone know how to do this? I can only find 'merge' things related to merging two *different* tables while in fact this is the *same* table, only distributed.

For me this is pretty essential for making my system 'eventually consistent'. I want to leverage postgresql's distributed database mechanics because they are so reliable, I wouldn't want to rewrite them.

Comment: Er, PostgreSQL doesn't *have* "distributed database mechanics". What database are *you* talking about? (It hopefully will in future though; see http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide for multi-master eventually consistent last-update-wins replication)

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find anything on the subject.

This is baffling. Which software indeed....

Comment: This moves the question.
Which database allows me to do what I described? Should I edit the question?

Comment: I'm still bewildered. You asserted that PostgreSQL's "distributed database mechanics ... [are] so reliable". What do you base that on, if it doesn't have any, and you couldn't find any information about the feature that doesn't exist? Maybe you were thinking of [Postgres-XC](http://postgresxc.wikia.com/wiki/Postgres-XC_Wiki), a fork that attempts to add multi-master transparent clustering? It isn't what you describe, though. Or maybe you were looking at [Bucardo](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bucardo), a 3rd party tool that runs on PostgreSQL? It's closer to what you're talking about.

Comment: I have yet to hear a negative story about PostgreSQL's reliability. Thus I asserted that it's distributed mechanisms are very good and reliable. I also wanted to prevent people from suggesting NoSQL databases and similar not-actually-what-I-want alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL has no "distributed database" features. You can't rewrite them or avoid rewriting them because they don't exist, and I'm quite curious about where you got your reliability information from.

The closest tihng I can think of is [a 3rd party addon called Bucardo](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bucardo), which does multi-master replication with conflict resolution.

It's also possible you were thinking of [Postgres-XC](http://postgresxc.wikia.com/wiki/Postgres-XC_Wiki), but that project is intended to produce a synchronous, consistent, transparent multi-master cluster, so there'd be no conflict resolution in the first place.

There's also Rubyrep; I don't know enough about it to know if it'd fit your needs.

In the future PostgreSQL will support something akin to what you are describing, with [logical replication / bi-directional replication](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide), but it's pre-alpha quality for now, and is likely to land in PostgreSQL 9.5 at the soonest.

Comment: I have yet to hear a negative story about PostgreSQL's reliability. Thus I asserted that it's distributed mechanisms are very good and reliable. I also wanted to prevent people from suggesting NoSQL databases and similar not-actually-what-I-want alternatives.

Comment: Thanks! I think Bucardo is actually what I intended. It's still a bit limited, but it seems like what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Lodewijk Cool. In future, hopefully BDR will fit your needs, but it's not ready yet.